# Make extjs textarea non editable

Tags: javascript, extjs

How can I make a textarea field non editable in extjs 4? I see the API [extjs textarea](http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.form.field.TextArea.html), but i dont see editable property. I need only to show text messages in the text area but I would also like it to autoscroll when there is more text in it, which textarea component can provide, but still I dont want it editable.

Or should I use different text component?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the config `readOnly:true`